# Minimal variance of random variable that guarantees solution to equation

Tags: calculus, probability-distributions

Let $\tilde{\theta}$ be a random variable with mean $1$ and support $[0, \overline{\theta}]$ (where $\overline{\theta} > 1$), with continuous, differentiable and strictly positive density $f(\theta)$ (CDF $F(\theta)$) over the interior of its support.

I have the following equation:

$g(\theta) := M[1-\delta + \delta F(\theta)] - \delta \theta f(\theta) \stackrel{!}{=} 0$,

where $M \geq 1$ and $\delta \in (0,1)$. Note that $g(0) = M(1-\delta) > 0$.

I am looking for a (preferably tight) bound on the variance of $\tilde{\theta}$ which guarantees a solution of the above equation, given the parameters $M$ and $\delta$. Is there a clean way to do this? Thanks in advance!